# SQL Server 2005 Performance Audit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance

Do you guys have any good step by step type links for performing an SQL Server 2005 Performance Audit?

Something like this [link](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/How-to-Perform-a-SQL-Server-Performance-Audit/) would be great but for SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you've really answered your own question here!  Brad McGehee's article is still 100% relevant for sql server 2005.  There's some places which need updating, but it's still quite comprehensive.

**EDIT**
Brad has an  updated 2005 version for performance auditing sql server 2005!
Check these out:
[SQL Server 2005 Performance Audit : Introduction](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/audit/2005_audit_operating_system_p1.aspx)
[SQL Server 2005 Server Configuration Performance Audit Checklist : Part 1](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/audit/2005_server_configuration_pt1_p1.aspx)
[SQL Server 2005 Server Configuration Performance Audit Checklist : Part 2](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/audit/2005_server_configuration_pt2_p1.aspx)
[SQL Server 2005 Performance Audit : Operating System Configuration Performance Checklist](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/audit/2005_audit_operating_system_p1.aspx)